# How to use non-compliant selectors?

Tags: sass

Is it possible to output a selector that isn't compliant with CSS standards? For example, I want to use this selector:

`Button < Icon {}`

But sass complains because it doesn't know what to do about the `<`. I'm thinking there has to be a way to output the selector without it being parsed by sass.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

sass eventually will be parsed to css and `<` is not valid css operator. This `<` fake operator would be an attempt to select a direct Parent from a given child, like `>` selects a direct child from given parent. CSS doesn't allow that. As its name says `cascading style sheets`, you go top from bottom, you can only select children, siblings at best, but no parents.

Preprocessors let you write easier styling with function, mixins, cleaner syntaxes, but dont allow you to violate css basic rules, you cant go around it.